# Xpages error on one database in XPINC

Tags: xpages

My Xpages app on the server runs fine for everyone except one user. I have an Xpage that let's the user select from some drop downs and then does a partial refresh on a view container that subsets the view. Works great.

When he makes selections sometimes the partial refresh does not fire. Also, when he goes to the page two date values are already filled in (with June 4, 2014) when they should not be filled in.

I VNCed into his machine and looked at the Xpages error log. He has strange errors that I have never seen before.

I googled this to no avail.

Any Java experts that have some idea what this means.

Is there something stuck in his local cache that is causing this, that I can just delete?

Bryan

```
    6/4/14 12:25 PM: Exception Thrown
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.Stream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.WriteStream.flushMyBuf(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.WriteStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.ResponseStream.writeChunk(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.ResponseStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.ResponseStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.WriteStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.commons.util.io.ByteStreamCache.copyTo(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse.commitResponse(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)

    console_WS0994_2014_06_04@12_24_25.log
    [0710:0002-1924] 06/04/2014 12:24:25.52 PM DeskClientOpenInt> Calling CreateProgramRCP pszRCPCmdLine[/authenticate "=C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\notes.ini"] bDeskProvisioningRestart [0]
    [0710:0002-1924] 06/04/2014 12:24:25.52 PM DeskClientOpenInt> DESK_CHECKNOTES2ALIVE_TIMER started
    [0710:0002-1924] 06/04/2014 12:24:25.52 PM DeskClientOpenInt> Executed CreateProgramRCP
    [1438:0002-0550] 06/04/2014 12:24:29.67 PM InitGlobalProcessInfo> PID [5176]!= [0]  
    [0710:0002-1924] 06/04/2014 12:24:37 PM  Connected to server KC1/Scoular
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:57 PM  Dynamic Client Configuration started
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:57 PM  Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:57 PM  Dynamic Client Configuration updating policy information
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:57 PM  Dynamic Client Configuration: Applying policy bookmarks
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:58 PM  Dynamic Client Configuration updating location information
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:58 PM  Dynamic Client Configuration updating location information using policy
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:58.01 PM DynConfig> Found $DPLocked field: $DPLocked on policy note.  Copying to location doc
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:58.01 PM DynConfig> Found $DPLocked field: $DPLockedUnstripped on policy note.  Copying to location doc
    [1D24:0002-0588] 06/04/2014 12:24:58 PM  Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown


    6/4/14 12:25 PM: Exception Thrown
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.Stream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.WriteStream.flushMyBuf(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.WriteStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.ResponseStream.writeChunk(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.ResponseStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.ResponseStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.io.WriteStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.commons.util.io.ByteStreamCache.copyTo(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse.commitResponse(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the XPiNC app set to run locally or on the server? It may have an impact. From that I'd check the settings with a user for whom it works, particularly ECL settings (unless those are enforced via a policy).

It looks like it's hitting an error when writing, using the socket. XPiNC adds a port number onto localhost. Is there a conflict with another application on the PC using the port? That could explain occasional issues and explain why it was only happening for one user. You should be able to use the XSPUrl class to find the port, if it's not anywhere else.

The other thing that springs to mind is checking access to temp folders where it serializes / deserializes page data, though I would expect that to result in consistent failing. XPages Portable Command Guide would probably tell you the default locations.

The date problem sounds very strange and isn't explained by any of the things I've mentioned so far, but it may be a separate issue.